# Where can I learn the all the Linux process lists in detail which comes with ps

Tags: linux, centos5

Ween I do `ps -A`

Then I get the list of all processes. Is there any tutorial which explains which process is doing what?

Answer (score 3):

Usually you'll get an idea what each process does in its man page. Just run `man $processname` (e. g. `man init`) to open the corresponding man page.

Processes shown within square brackets in the output of `ps -ef` (e. g. `[kthreadd]`) are kernel process for which you won't find a man page.

Comment: Is there any place on web where i can get kernel process info

Comment: The kernel processes are usually described in the documentation of the respective kernel subsystem, see http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-2.6.34.y.git;a=tree;f=Documentation

Answer (score 0):

ps -A x will list the processes as well as the command line arguments used (which is really useful). netstat -tup will list all tcp and udp connections as well as the process driving those connections. Run as root if some process ids are blanked out. lsof -p pid will list all the open handles currently owned by the process associated with pid. This information usually encapsulates files and sockets, very useful for figuring if a process has got a lock on a file. grep, awk, sort and uniq are great tools for ordering and filtering the data generated by the ps, netstat and lsof commands.